# Why doesn't "exit" show as a PowerShell command?

Tags: powershell

Noticed something curious today. We all (probably) know `exit` will end your current PowerShell session (or exit a remote `PSSession`). However, neither `Get-Command` or `Get-Alias` return anything for it (errors truncated below):

```
Get-Command exit # ==> The term 'exit' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet....
Get-Alias exit # ====> This command cannot find a matching alias....
```

So... what is it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`exit` is a keyword, not a command/cmdlet. See [about_Language_Keywords](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_language_keywords) for more information.

Others keywords (eg. `if`) also exhibit the same behavior when used with Get-Command / Get-Alias.